# How to open a php page on the right side when I click a link?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I am a newbie of HTML.
I wish to do a function when a link is clicked, another .php page is show on the right side.
I am not sure is this related to AJAX function or SCRIPT.

Click here:
[This is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHmh7.png)

Click here: 
[This is example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZoJP.png)

Thus, each time i click different label, different .php page was shown on right side.

This is part of the code.

```
  <li class="nav-header">MENAMBAH MAKLUMAT</li>
          <li><a href="#"></i>Resident</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"></i>Pentadbir</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"></i>Soalan-soalan lazim</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"></i>Annoucement</a></li>
```

and I have resident.php and annoucement.php with me too.
I need guidance on how to make this work.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think [pjax](http://pjax.heroku.com/) is what you're looking for.

Not only does it handle loading page fragments asynchronously (what you're asking in your question), you also get `pushState` help which means the location bar is updated when content is changed. This helps keep track of browser history so that when your visitor hit's the back button, they go where they expect to. It also means they can bookmark or share the right page too.

Comment: Thank you. But how can I make the .php page to the right side of this MENU page?

Answer (score 0):

try like this.

```
<li class="nav-header">MENAMBAH MAKLUMAT</li>
          <li><a href="#" data-link="resident"></i>Resident</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" data-link="Pentadbir"></i>Pentadbir</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" data-link="Soalan"></i>Soalan-soalan lazim</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" data-link="Annoucement"></i>Annoucement</a></li>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(function(){
   $('li a').on('click',function(){

       var link =$(this).data('link');
       switch(link)
       {
       case 'resident':
       $('div').load('resident.php');
       //load resident.php(use load()for loading pages)
       break;
       ---
       ---
       }
   });

});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: where should I insert the Jquery?
in header? php? body?

Comment: You can insert jquery in header.make sure that jquery core file is included.

Comment: Sorry. I am so dump. Where to get jquery core file?

Comment: Download it from jquery.com. check this link http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

Comment: Yes. I done with the jquery.
what is that 'div' means in line 8? is that variable name for my desired div?

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using AJAX.

1. Add one ajax.php with the code:

   ```
   <script type='text/javascript'>

   function ajax(page,div)
   {
   var xmlhttp;
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
     {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
     xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
     }
   else
     {// code for IE6, IE5
     xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
     }
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
     {
     if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
       {
       document.getElementById(div).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
       }
     }
   xmlhttp.open('GET',page);
   xmlhttp.send();
   }
   </script>

   "; ?>
   ```
2. Include ajax.php in your php page.
3. Define a `div` with `id="mydiv"` in your php page, then on the link, add in `onClick="ajax('caripenghuni.php','mydiv2')"`

For example, 
`<li><a href="#" onClick="ajax('resident.php','mydiv2')">Resident</a></li>`